# knitr, R Markdown, and xtable: xtable tables within HTML table

Tags: html, r, knitr, xtable

Suppose I want to print HTML tables using xtable, side-by-side. I tried doing this in an .Rmd file with:

```
<table border = 1>
<tr>
<td>
`r functionThatPrintsAnHTMLTableUsingxtable`
</td>
<td>
`r functionThatPrintsAnotherHTMLTableUsingxtable`
</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

No dice. What am I doing wrong? Thanks.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I think your code will work if you put `results=asis` in the chunk options.

````
<table border = 1>
<tr>
<td>
```{r results='asis', echo=FALSE}
  library(xtable)
  data(tli)
  print(xtable(tli[1:20, ]),type='html')
```
</td>
<td>
```{r results='asis', echo=FALSE}
  library(xtable)
  data(tli)
  print(xtable(tli[1:20, ]),type='html',comment=FALSE)
```
</td>
</tr>
</table>
````

Comment: There is one issue with this: For some reason, an HTML comment tag shows up with the second table. This is fixed by specifying the `comment` attribute of `print.xtable()` as `FALSE`