# latex table not in html. R knitr spin latex kable xtable RStudio

Tags: html, r, latex, knitr

Below is my R script, and the resulting html, which is not including the latex tables.
I'm using RStudio and knitr's spin function to produce the output.
If I change the output to pdf_document the tables output as expected.

```
#' ---
#' title: "Sample"
#' author: "Joe_Schmoe"
#' output: html_document
#' ---

#+ results='asis'
library(xtable)
data("tli")
xtable(head(tli))

library(knitr)
kable(head(tli), format="latex")
```

```html
<body>

<style type="text/css">
.main-container {
  max-width: 940px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}
code {
  color: inherit;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.04);
}
img { 
  max-width:100%; 
  height: auto; 
}
</style>
<div class="container-fluid main-container">


<div id="header">
<h1 class="title">Sample</h1>
<h4 class="author"><em>Joe_Schmoe</em></h4>
<h4 class="date"><em>Wed Nov 18 14:17:44 2015</em></h4>
</div>


<pre class="r"><code>library(xtable)
data(&quot;tli&quot;)
xtable(head(tli))</code></pre>
% latex table generated in R 3.2.2 by xtable 1.8-0 package % Wed Nov 18 14:17:44 2015

<pre class="r"><code>library(knitr)
kable(head(tli), format=&quot;latex&quot;)</code></pre>

<pre class="r"><code>sessionInfo()</code></pre>
<p>R version 3.2.2 (2015-08-14) Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit) Running under: Windows 7 x64 (build 7601) Service Pack 1</p>
<p>locale: [1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252 [2] LC_CTYPE=English_United States.1252<br />[3] LC_MONETARY=English_United States.1252 [4] LC_NUMERIC=C<br />[5] LC_TIME=English_United States.1252</p>
<p>attached base packages: [1] stats graphics grDevices utils datasets methods base</p>
<p>other attached packages: [1] knitr_1.10.5 xtable_1.8-0</p>
<p>loaded via a namespace (and not attached): [1] magrittr_1.5 formatR_1.2 tools_3.2.2 htmltools_0.2.6 [5] yaml_2.1.13 stringi_1.0-1 rmarkdown_0.6.1 stringr_1.0.0<br /> [9] digest_0.6.8 evaluate_0.7</p>


</div>

<script>

// add bootstrap table styles to pandoc tables
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('tr.header').parent('thead').parent('table').addClass('table table-condensed');
});

</script>

<!-- dynamically load mathjax for compatibility with self-contained -->
<script>
  (function () {
    var script = document.createElement("script");
    script.type = "text/javascript";
    script.src  = "https://cdn.mathjax.org/mathjax/latest/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS-MML_HTMLorMML";
    document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(script);
  })();
</script>

</body>
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21397407/knitr-r-markdown-and-xtable-xtable-tables-within-html-table

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking me to do.  I have `#+ results='asis'` and it works for pdf, just not for html.  I also want the prettier latex table as opposed to an html table.

Comment: print(xtable(tli[1:20, ]),type='html',comment=FALSE))