# Use xtable to print html table in R markdown file

Tags: r, r-markdown, xtable

I would like to print a nicer table with a data frame in R mark down file, and I know how to use `kable` to print it, but I'd like a little bit more control options for which I am experimenting with the `xtable` package. However, I am really stuck with a silly problem which is that it doesn't print the table but `html` code in the file. So for example, if I want to print a default data set `cars` I would do:

````
```{r}
library(xtable)
print(xtable(head(cars)), type = "html")
```
````

which gives me this piece of html code.

```
## <!-- html table generated in R 3.2.5 by xtable 1.8-2 package -->
## <!-- Wed May 25 19:06:33 2016 -->
## <table border=1>
## <tr> <th>  </th> <th> speed </th> <th> dist </th>  </tr>
##   <tr> <td align="right"> 1 </td> <td align="right"> 4.00 </td> <td align="right"> 2.00 </td> </tr>
##   <tr> <td align="right"> 2 </td> <td align="right"> 4.00 </td> <td align="right"> 10.00 </td> </tr>
##   <tr> <td align="right"> 3 </td> <td align="right"> 7.00 </td> <td align="right"> 4.00 </td> </tr>
##   <tr> <td align="right"> 4 </td> <td align="right"> 7.00 </td> <td align="right"> 22.00 </td> </tr>
##   <tr> <td align="right"> 5 </td> <td align="right"> 8.00 </td> <td align="right"> 16.00 </td> </tr>
##   <tr> <td align="right"> 6 </td> <td align="right"> 9.00 </td> <td align="right"> 10.00 </td> </tr>
##    </table>
```

But I want an html table instead of the `html` code being displayed. Does anybody have any suggestions?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21397407/knitr-r-markdown-and-xtable-xtable-tables-within-html-table

Comment: I've actually tried that. It's not really working for me.

Comment: Sorry for the typo. After fixing that, it gives me the same result.

Comment: are you doing this? http://i.imgur.com/ubsnZ8m.png

Comment: Ahh. I did try that. But I was using the `result` as the parameter `results` so it didn't work. Now it's working. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Make sure to put 'asis' in quotes.

````
```{r, results='asis'}
library(xtable)
print(xtable(head(cars)), type = "html")
```
````

[image]